# Block request to certain url call from server

Tags: block

i have website running , that call url of some other website is there any way to block call to particular website.

For eg : inside some part of my website a call is made to url like

```
abc.com/xxx/aa
```

Please not abc.com is 3rd party website url

no i want to block any request from my server to abc.com

how can i do it.

will blocking ip of that server will work ?
or should i put something in .htacess or shh to make it work

Below is what i am trying to do 
image url : `https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg`

page content:(a.php)

```
<img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg"/>
```

Now i want when i open a.php

that image must not show

Answer (score 1):

You can use below configuration in apache to block Specific URI

```
<Location /xxx/aa>
     Order Allow,Deny
     deny from 255.0.0.0
     deny from 123.45.6.
     allow from all
</Location>
```

To block specific URL with some URI for particular IP

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule ^xxx/aa? - [F,NC]
```

Comment: hi i need to block whole url call you can say abc.com/* in your answer where i can not see abc.com

Comment: Please check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use iptables to block the entire url from being hit by your server, including obviously your site.

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d URL_YOU_WANT_TO_BLOCK -j DROP`

But this might be overkill depending on your use case.